# When/how to initialize a socket in a controller

Tags: angularjs

I have a controller, that whenever a URL in this controller is accessed I want to establish a socket connection.  I'm creating a socket service and am wondering when/how to instantiate it.  I realize I could use `$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function () {});` to monitor my URL for anything `/approval`, but it seems like there's probably a better way.  **Where's the best place to initialize the socket connection when a given controller's route is accessed?**

Currently I'm just initializing it in the configuration to test my module, but long term this won't work, because I'll have 4-5 controllers that involve sockets and the socket that is used depends on which controller you're accessing.  A user will only ever be directed to 1 of the potential 5 socket/controller combinations which is why I can't have all of the controllers establish their socket in the controller config.

```
angular.module('workstation.process.approval', [
        /* Dependencies */
        'workstation.services'
    ]).

    config(['$routeProvider', 'SocketServiceProvider', function($routeProvider, SocketServiceProvider) {
        SocketServiceProvider.connect('/socket/workstation/approval');

        /* URL mappings */
        $routeProvider.
            when('/approval', {templateUrl: '/partials/loading.htm',   controller: 'ApprovalCtrl'}).
            when('/approval/dashboard', {templateUrl: '/partials/approval/dashboard.htm',   controller: 'ApprovalCtrl'})
    }]).

    controller('ApprovalCtrl', ['$scope', '$cookieStore', 'WorkflowProcessService', 'WorkstationService', 'SocketService', 'socketUrl', '$location', function ($scope, $cookieStore, WorkflowProcessService, WorkstationService, SocketService, socketUrl, $location) {
     //my controller
}]);
```

Comment: you could put a common resolve property on all controllers and initialize socket inside that resolve function .For deep understanding study the resolve property in routeprovider

Comment: @Ajaybeniwal - That's a good thought.  So I could setup a method that establishes the socket connection only once, and pass that through the resolve property on all routes.... Can you post this as an answer, I want to give others more time to post potential solutions, but I may end up doing it this way.